# Prevent password SSH access to your own account without root access

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have user access to a server which enables SSH access through passwords. However, I want to disable that access for my own user and only connect through a RSA key. I don't have root access to the server. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you,
R.

Comment: While you can't delete your own password to disable password based logins, and you can't edit the sshd_config file to disable password authentication for yourself, you could create a massively long password for yourself if you can't manage to get this disabled. I'm assuming security is your motivator when stating this.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it might be an idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. You can request the administrator to disable password based logins for your specific account though by having them set  in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match user rhobincu
   PasswordAuthentication no
```